# NSURL to access files on network share in Cocoa - Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am trying to write a small Mac command line app that can read and write XML files to a server on my local network.  I have tried creating an NSURL like this:

```
NSURL *urlToFileOnServer = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Volumes/{name of folder}/{etc...}/file.xml" isDirectory:NO];
```

And then I check its existence with:

```
[urlToFileOnServer checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&err]
```

but it always responds with file not found (I have confirmed that the file is there as seen by the finder).

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong with the URL?  I am hoping that once I get the URL right I can use NSFileHandle to write to it.  BTW... The file is on a MacMini running OS X server that I am accessing over WiFi.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting the volume name: `@"/Volumes/{volume name}/{name of folder}/{etc...}/file.xml"`

Comment: Thanks... but tried that and with the name on the volume on my desktop and I still get: "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory".  As a check I went into terminal and followed the path and I get into the volume, but ls shows no files?

Comment: Try dragging the file from the Finder window into the Terminal window, it will put it's path there.

Comment: Thank You, Thank You, Thank You!  The correct mounted volume had a "-1" appended.  I had been looking in the non "-1" volume.  Everything now works as expected.